# When I use Promise with dialogflow library in server - get Error

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I try to execute this code on Firebase Cloud Functions

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firebase_database = require('./conf/firebase');
const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
     function searcheColleagueByName(agent){
       var lastname = agent.parameters.lastname;        
       firebase_database.ref().once('value')
       .then(team => {
           agent.add("some name " + lastname);
        })
       .catch(err=>{
           agent.add("something wrong");
       })
     }
```

and after when i make request to my bot from telegram I get error in firebase console:

```
Error: No responses defined for platform: null
    at V2Agent.sendResponses_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:243:13)
    at WebhookClient.send_ (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:505:17)
    at promise.then (/srv/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:316:38)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

What's wrong? why when I use `promisse` my agent can't give me an answer?

Comment: You only *define* a function in the body of the `onRequest` callback; you don't do or return anything. NB: where would you get the value of `agent` from? Also, your code has more opening parentheses and braces than closing ones. Please take care of indenting you code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, if you're using an async function, then your intent handler must also return a Promise. It isn't enough that you send the reply as part of the `then()` clause, you must also return the Promise that the `then()` is part of.

In your case, this looks fairly easy. In the `searchColleagueByName()` function, you would return then `once().then().catch()` result, which is a Promise. (Since `then()` and `catch()` return a Promise.)

So it might look something like this:

```
   return firebase_database.ref().once('value')
   .then(team => {
       agent.add("some name " + lastname);
    })
   .catch(err=>{
       agent.add("something wrong");
   })
```